# Front end user experience for employees

Tags: user-interface

I am brand new to Wordpress, Civi CRM and most IT so I will apologise in advance if this is a silly question.
I have installed Civi CRM to Wordpress using a subdomain of our website for the not for profit organisation I work for. I am trying to create a CRM system to manage staff/volunteer information, keep a record of history and contacts, and upload documents to profiles. I also want to assign tasks and reminders to individual profiles. Can you tell me how I move Civi CRM into a user friendly page for employees to access with a username and password that does not take them in to the wordpress (i dont want them to access settings, etc)
If I look at the "pages" section, it is empty and there is no way of bringing civi crm on to the page eaily from what I can see, or ensuring it is only accessible by staff instead of the general public. I should probably be using a professional to do this, but budgets are tight and I am hoping to find a way of doing it myself

Comment: Hi - welcome - it can help others help you if you can reference which documentation you followed in doing your set up. In terms of 'access', you may want to compare your set up with https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ which you can login to as an Admin. If you go to this page you will see you can set access permissions to civicrm for different WP user roles https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess&reset=1

Comment: also (i am more familiar with Drupal) i believe there are some WP extensions that are helpful/recommended that you may want to consider eg https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/

Comment: I expect someone who knows WP well will come along soon and answer your specific question. if not, and if you are in a hurry, you may want to join https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/wordpress which gets more/different/quicker eyeballs perhaps than here